# How to read x amount of characters from a text file

Tags: java

How can I read 20 characters of a text file progressively, for example, If i have a function read_next, calling it the first time would return the first 20 characters in a string, calling it the second time would return the next 20 characters of the file. Please note, I don't want to read the whole file into an array then break it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you want to use [`InputStream#read(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d%29)

> Reads some number of bytes from the input stream and stores them into
>   the buffer array b. The number of bytes actually read is returned as
>   an integer

```
public int read(InputStream is, byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
    return is.read(bytes);
}
```

Then you basically want to call this method...

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[20];
int bytesRead = -1;
while ((bytesRead = read(is, bytes)) != -1) {
    // Process the bytes..
    // Note, while bytes.length will always == 20
    // there will only ever be bytesRead worth of 
    // values in the array
}
```

**UPDATED**

After some nice feedback, you could also apply the same idea to UFT-8 encoded file using a `Reader`

```
public int read(Reader reader, char[] chars) throws IOException {
    return reader.read(chars);
}
```

And call the method as such...

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("file"), "UTF-8");
char[] chars = new char[20];
int charsRead = -1;
while ((charsRead = read(reader, chars)) != -1) {
    // Process chars, the same caveats apply as above...
}
```

Comment: if is only ASCII characters, than this method meet your needs, if UFT-8, than not :D

Comment: @matheszabi Fair point. The actually requirements are a little vague as it doesn't specify how the characters are to be read (`InputStream` or `Reader`) +1 to your comment

Answer (score 0):

I would read with a BufferedReader a line. It can be the whole file :(
Hopefully not.

You can read a specified amount of bytes, but those can be more than the characters ( utf-8)